# Raspberry Pi Zero W Boot Loop

Tags: pi-zero-w, boot-issues

I manage four Raspberry Pi Zero W’s in a signage display project. I recently flashed all four of my units from Raspberry Pi OS to BalenaOS. I made sure that the new image I’ve downloaded is compatible with the Zero W as well, but on all four of my units, they seem to be stuck in some sort of boot loop where the lights come up for a few seconds, the display turns on like an input has been connected, but nothing more than that. Does anyone have any pointers I could try?

Video of one of the Pis in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0PQc.jpg

I’ve also tried reflashing the OS to each card and swapping out the power supplies, but it shouldn’t be the power supplies as they’re the CanaKit power supplies.

Edit: The white dongle shown in the video is a micro USB to Ethernet adapter. I read online that boot problems could be from USB devices drawing too much power. I cut the power to the Pi, unplugged this adapter and turned power back on to try to boot, but the same thing happened so I don’t think it’s that adapter. It was also running perfectly fine before on the same exact hardware.

Comment: next step is to flash Raspberry Pi OS to one of the SD cards and run that

Comment: @jsotola — Thanks for the suggestion. It was previously running both BalenaOS and Raspberry Pi OS just fine, I’ll try putting it back to Raspberry Pi OS again. If that boots, what would the next steps be?

Comment: that would indicate that the BalenaOS download is either the wrong version for the hardware or that the download is somehow corrupted or that the SD card has some kind of a problem

Comment: I don't think this can be reproduced by anyone besides yourself. Unless of course BalenaOS is such an unstable OS that even the vanilla image doesn't boot.

Comment: Feel free to share your issues with the balenaOS version on the balena forums at https://forums.balena.io